# Vibration when at a stop and in reverse gear, check engine light back on

Tags: rough-idle, evap

I have a 2004 chevy classic. At first my engine light was on and i got the O2 sensor fixed at chevy dealership and then it went off. It came back on the next day. I took it back to Chevy dealership and they held it for a day and told me that it was a wire that they fixed. No signs of engine issues they said. The check engine light was off but i still had a rough idle at a stop or when im reversing. I got the spark plugs replaced but it didn't fix the problem so i replaced the air filter but car still had bad vibrations. Thought about it being my brakes so i got the rear brakes completely done, the fronts still need pads and calibers. Guy told me the brakes has nothing to do with the vibrations at a stop or in reverse only when braking. About four days after the second visit from chevy the engine light came back on, i went to AutoZone to get the engine light checked out and got a PO455 code. Which indicates a leak in the evap or no flow. Im going back to the dealership on monday but i also tried to replace the fuel cap and clean the injectors by putting a 16 oz of seafoam in the gas tank that was 1/4 filed and then add more gas til it reached 1/2 a tank. Now i hear a noise that happens when im accelerating that sounds like a bad scraping or metal screeching im not sure. I don't know what this problem can be and i don't want to keep wasting money.

Comment: do not drive your car with the scraping sound present,you have paid to get the car repaired so this is now the problem for the repairshop,you will probably have to pay for the parts but the work should be free of charge for you.be sure to keep any documents in case you get problems with the repairshop.

Comment: Okay i will definitely take your advice. So this is a issue they should have corrected when i paid for the diagnosis? Or did seafoam mess my engine up worse?

Comment: i do not think the seafoam is the main cause for your problem,if it is the problem should go away next time you fill your tank.please update your question after you get the diagnostic answer from the repairshop.